# Need to add Attributes in AuthNRequest.. How can this be done?

Tags: itfoxtec-identity-saml2

How can this example be added to the Assertion with itfoxtec-identity-saml2 in C#? Cant find an adequate method...

```
<saml:AttributeStatement>
<saml:Attribute FriendlyName="SurName" Name="urn:oid:2.5.4.4" NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:uri">
  <saml:AttributeValue xsi:type="xs:string">Max</saml:AttributeValue>
</saml:Attribute>
<saml:Attribute FriendlyName="CommonName" Name="urn:oid:2.5.4.3" NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:uri">
  <saml:AttributeValue xsi:type="xs:string">Max Mustermann</saml:AttributeValue>
</saml:Attribute>
<saml:Attribute Name="urn:oid:0.9.2342.19200300.100.1.1" NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:uri">
  <saml:AttributeValue xsi:type="xs:string">has</saml:AttributeValue>
</saml:Attribute>
<saml:Attribute FriendlyName="Email" Name="urn:oid:0.9.2342.19200300.100.1.3" NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:uri">
  <saml:AttributeValue xsi:type="xs:string">max@mustermann.de</saml:AttributeValue>
</saml:Attribute>  </saml:AttributeStatement>
```

Comment: Do you wan to add AttributeStatement in the AuthnRequest or in the Assertion issued in the AuthnResponse?

Comment: As I have understood, this will be sent with AuthNRequest and returned in the Assertion issued in the AuthNResponse

Comment: The AttributeStatements in the Assertion in the AuthnResponse is issued by the IdP. You can as an RP only provide a declaration of intent.

Comment: But in the test apps of itfoxtec-identity-saml2 the TestIdPCore project is acting as IdP. How do I configure it to pass these attributes?

Comment: Do you mean that I should extend the relying parties with this attributes?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to add more Claims/Attribute to the issued Assertion in the sample IdP.

The test users claims is added in
https://github.com/ITfoxtec/ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2/blob/master/test/TestIdPCore/Controllers/AuthController.cs#L173

You can add the needed Claims/Attribute which will then be issued in the AuthnResponse Assertion.

Comment: This are not custom attributes defined in the <saml:AttributeStatement> tag of the assertion. Claims are dependent on the given claimtypes in System.Security.Claims Namespace

Comment: You are not limited to use a claim type defined in System.Security.Claims, you can use your own custom claim type.

Answer (score 0):

Claims are limited to the claimtypes definded in the System.Security.Claims Namespace:

[image]

In ComponentsPro Saml implementation attributes are added like this:

```
 AttributeStatement attributeStatement = new AttributeStatement();
attributeStatement.Attributes.Add(new ComponentPro.Saml2.Attribute("email", SamlAttributeNameFormat.Basic, null,
                                                                             "john@test.com"));
attributeStatement.Attributes.Add(new ComponentPro.Saml2.Attribute("FirstName", SamlAttributeNameFormat.Basic, null,
                                                                             "John"));
attributeStatement.Attributes.Add(new ComponentPro.Saml2.Attribute("LastName", SamlAttributeNameFormat.Basic, null,
                                                                             "Smith"));

// Insert a custom token key to the SAML response.
attributeStatement.Attributes.Add(new ComponentPro.Saml2.Attribute("CustomTokenForVerification", SamlAttributeNameFormat.Basic, null,
                                                                             "YourEncryptedTokenHere"));

samlAssertion.Statements.Add(attributeStatement);
```

In Pingfederates Identity Service Provider connections there are custom attributes to be defined. This seems not to be a claim?

[image]